# Wordpress - change page background on menu hover

Tags: wordpress, menu, hover, slider, fullpage.js

What would be the most elegant way for a Wordpress site to have a full page background slide show that would switch between images on mouse hovering over certain menu items? Something like [this site here](http://www.graffdiamonds.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [BgStretcher](http://www.ajaxblender.com/bgstretcher-2-jquery-stretch-background-plugin-updated.html%22) to do it

Comment: AlexP the link doesn't seem to work. Is that the same BgStretcher plugin being sold at ThemeForest? Because that one has no information about whether it will be able to change the site's backgruond if I hover my mouse over menu items. In any case, it's not a Wordpress plugin, it's a Jquery plugin

Comment: you will need to customize action to make it work on hover.  And yes, it is same like on code canyon        http://codecanyon.net/item/bgstretcher-jquery-background-resizer-slideshow/5328926?ref=w3blender